# video compression in vb 2005?

Tags: vb.net, video, compression, directx

i wanted to ask is there any means i can compress a video file(.avi) to a small size than original.

If yes..how..?

A sample code/tutorial to do so would be of great help

Which API should i use(except the DirectX)..?

Is DirectX advisable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ffmpeg.Net http://www.codeplex.com/ffmpegdotnet

Comment: when i go to that link..it says the project has no releases..?how do i download it..?

Comment: it looks like you can get the source on the right side of http://ffmpegdotnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

Comment: when i browse the code on my right hand side..it contains all .h and .cpp files...how do i use it with my vb.net 2005 app..?

Comment: You would have to open the project in visual studio (c++ application) then compile it.  You would then reference the compiled dll's in your vb.net app.